# How to Use grep to find '../images/'

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, grep

How do you use grep to find occurrences of strings in a directory, when the string to search for is '../images/'?  This is the command as I normally use it

```
grep -H -r 'string to find' /path/to/dir
```

Some search characters cause problems, and evidently '../' is among those.

I tried various combinatrions of  \ in front of some characters This is a search I need to do frequently, to find references in css files that are pointing to images in the folder next door.

Comment: You could also use `fgrep`, if available on your platform, which does not treat "." as special characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot matches any character with grep.   You need to prefix it with a backslash, e.g `'\.\./images/'`

Comment: I thought I tried that but I must not have.  This worked perfect:  grep -H -r '\.\.images/'   Are the search rules for this the same as regex?

Comment: grep is the original regex -- yeah, just like that.

Comment: Patrick, with that edit you just put up that is the answer.  I have to wait a few minutes to accept.

Comment: Sorry -- I'm still sorta new to this.  Thanks for the heads-up on that, I'll bear it in mind in the future!